# TimePicker Cypress automation

Tags: material-ui, cypress

I am finding difficulties in automating TimePicker through a clock in cypress. The component is through MaterialUI. It clicks on the value but the needle simply doesn't move. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The clock does not like `cy.click()` for some reason.

But you can test it with [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin

- install with `npm install cypress-real-events`
- add this line `import "cypress-real-events/support";` to the file `/cypress/support/e2e.js`

Test the clock like this:

```js
cy.get('button[aria-label^="Choose time"]').click()

cy.get('.MuiClockPicker-root').within(() => {

  cy.contains('12').realClick()   // choose 12 hours
  cy.contains('30').realClick()   // choose 30 minutes
})

// verify value
cy.get('input[placeholder="hh:mm (a|p)m"]').should('have.attr', 'value', '12:30 PM')

// or
cy.get('input[value="12:30 PM"]')
```